# How to call C# (in a .WSP web part) from Javascript (in a Content Editor web part)

Tags: client-object-model, sandbox-solution

I have Javascript (Client Object Model) running in a Content Editor web part that controls other web parts on the page.  The JS COM is limited in what it can do, so I want to be able to call managed code (c#) at times to fill in the gaps.  But I can't figure out how to pass control from js to c# (and back).

This is SharePoint 2010 sandboxed shared/hosted environment (not O365 SharePoint Online).  So I believe the managed code must be in a WSP web part on the same page.  The site has anonymous access.

Can (how can) the JS call the c# code?

Comment: Why not create a custom webpart which has your javascript code and can just POST data to normal codebehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple (and hackish) solution is to simply look for normal POST request parameters in your Web Part and do some logic based on this.
Example Web Part code:

```
var incomingMessage = Context.Request["message"];
var message = string.Format("Hello {0}", incomingMessage);
Controls.Add(new Label { Text = message, CssClass = "hack" });
```

Example call/read with jQuery:

```
$.post(window.location.href, {message: 'world!'}, function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    var message = $data.find('.hack').text();
    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: You cannot create custom webservices in a sandboxed environment.

Comment: Good call @jasper, removed it from the answer. Thanks

Comment: Nice hack! One improvement: '.' (dot as url) should be replaced with `window.location.href` so that the same page is requested, not the url "folder" (SitePages, Pages) in some web templates.